# single style sheet across multiple knitr documents

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am new to `knitr`, and I am looking to use it to write many `knitr` documents which use the same shared "style sheet" for consistency.

I am hoping to write my phd thesis appendices in `knitr/LaTeX`.  I am in the process of creating a number of different statistical models which I want to describe in a consistent manner, so using the same headings, plot formats and layout etc.

Aside from putting all my header information for the packages I am using and my custom `LaTeX` commands into a separate file and using `\include{}` to pull them in at the start of each file, what more can I do to standardize my model descriptions?

**Edit**:
I want to have as little as possible in common across the multiple `knitr`  .Rnw  files.  In plain R, I would use a function to parameterize, in LaTeX, I use a parameterized documentclass - I can't see how to get this clean parametrization across multiple `knitr` documents without cutting and pasting lots of code and having the inevitable consistency mistakes.

*I need to create an example here - back later!*

Comment: For those who don't like my question, please explain what is less than perfect. Thanks

Comment: I think there are two sets of questions here, one set for LaTeX (better addressed on tex.stackexchange.com) and one for `knitr`.  I do think the question needs to be more specific ...

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I saw it as a general knitr programming style question, and less about the LaTeX, which is why I asked here rather than tex.SE.

Comment: For reference, Yihui's book on Knitr has a useful section "9.3 Child Documents" which seems to answer this neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use anything like the following at the start of your .Rmd file?

```
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis", fig.width= 4., fig.height= 4, fig.cap= "")
```

At least some of the aspects of plots and captions below them -- here eliminated -- will be the same.  I suspect there is much more to be done.