# knitr templates and child documents in a loop

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Before Christmas I previously asked [single style sheet across multiple knitr documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370584/single-style-sheet-across-multiple-knitr-documents).  I now know that the key search term I was missing is "child document".

I have created a minimal markdown example but I am getting headers in the created document that are part of the knitting process.  I am using RStudio to process it.  I have seen many similar questions, but none of the answers work.  I have tried various combinations of the chunk parameters and so far to no avail.

*Question:* How do I get rid of the header from the final knitted document?

````
# Master document

```{r master1, comment='', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis", fig.width= 4., fig.height= 4, fig.cap= ""}
out = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  # lets create three different uniform data sets.
  v1 <- sort(rnorm(2))
  uvec <- runif(10, v1[[1]], v1[[2]])
  # now we want to 
  out <- c(out, knit_child('child.Rmd'))
}
cat(paste(out, collapse = '\n'))
```
````

The child document contains:

````
## child document `r i`

Here is a summary of the dataset:
```{r echo=FALSE}
summary(uvec)
```
````

Unfortunately I also get an annoying header ....

```
|
| | 0% |
|…………………. | 33% inline R code fragments

|
|……………………………………. | 67% label: unnamed-chunk-1

|
|………………………………………………………..| 100% ordinary text without R code

|
| | 0% |
|…………………. | 33% inline R code fragments

|
|……………………………………. | 67% label: unnamed-chunk-2

|
|………………………………………………………..| 100% ordinary text without R code

|
| | 0% |
|…………………. | 33% inline R code fragments

|
|……………………………………. | 67% label: unnamed-chunk-3

|
|………………………………………………………..| 100% ordinary text without R code
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One answer is to use `knit_expand()` instead of knit_child() and to `knit(, quiet=TRUE)` later - here is a revised master document.

````
# Master document
```{r master1, comment='', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis", fig.width= 4., fig.height= 4, fig.cap= ""}
out = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  # lets create three different uniform data sets.
  v1 <- sort(rnorm(2))
  uvec <- runif(10, v1[[1]], v1[[2]])
  out <- c(out, knit_expand('child.Rmd'))
}
cat(knit(text=unlist(paste(out, collapse = '\n')), quiet=TRUE))
```
````

Answer (score 14):

The [answer given by Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046060/817499) didn't work for me. The code that worked for me was:

````
# Master document

```{r echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

out = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  # lets create three different uniform data sets.
  v1 <- sort(rnorm(2))
  uvec <- runif(10, v1[[1]], v1[[2]])
  out <- c(out, knit_child('child.Rmd'))
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
cat(paste(out, collapse = '\n'))
```
````

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with Latex instead of markdown and the solution for me was to use the `\Sexpr` instead of a code block

In addition, `knit_child('child.file', quiet=TRUE)` works as well