# How to automate nested sections in Rmds which include text, maps and tables

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, knitr

I found several examples ([How to extract the content of SQL-Files using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35085464/5784831), 
[Use loop to generate section of text in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36674824/5784831), 
[Automating the generation of preformated text in Rmarkdown using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48868942/5784831)), but none
works in my case with nested sections including figures. Expected output:

[image]

It seems, I need some way to handle the included code chunks (e.g. ```` cat("```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}\n") ... cat("```\n") ```` properly, but I can't find a way.

**Edit**: I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27234462/5784831), but still can't make it work

````
kexpand <- function(chunkname, fig.width, fig.height) {
  cat(knitr::knit(text = knitr::knit_expand(text = 
     sprintf("```{r %s, fig.width=%s, fig.height=%s}\n.chunk_code\n", 
             chunkname, fig.width, fig.height))))
}
````

and then in the chunks:

```
  .chunk_code <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[i])
  kexpand(i, 8.4, 7)
```

**Edit 2**: There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50467457/5784831). Although it seems to be close, it still does not work. See also my approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986638/can-rs-htmltoolsincludehtml-not-handle-leaflet-maps) which I use because I have nested list - **I do not want all figures next to each other.**

---

All sections include the same type of figures, but the content changes of course. Below you find a

- the best I got so far and
- reference Rmd which shows the expeted output but with copy-paste chunks

Examples:

````
---
title: "The best I got"
author: "SQC"
date: "11 Juli 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7)
library(leaflet)
ranges <- paste0("section_", c(1:3))
```

# Title level 1

This is an R Markdown document. 

## Title level 2 (tab) {.tabset}

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:length(ranges)) {
  cat(paste0("#### Title level 4 `r ", 
             ranges[i], "` vs. `r ", ranges[i - 1], "` {.tabset}\n"))
  cat("##### Map\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}\n")
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[i])
  cat("```\n")
  # //

  cat("##### Tabelle\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r}\n")
  DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                rownames = FALSE)
  cat("```\n")
  # //
}
```

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:length(ranges)) {
  cat(paste0("#### `r ", ranges[i], "` vs. `r ", ranges[i - 1], "` {.tabset}\n"))
  cat("##### Karte\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}\n")
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[i])
  cat("```\n")
  # //

  cat("##### Tabelle\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r}\n")
  DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                rownames = FALSE)
  cat("```\n")
  # // 
}
```
````

---

````
---
title: "Reference"
author: "SQC"
date: "11 Juli 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(leaflet)
ranges <- paste0("section_", c(1:4))
```

# Title level 1

This is an R Markdown document. 

## Title level 2 (tab) {.tabset}

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[2]` vs. `r ranges[1]` {.tabset}

##### Karte
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[2])
```

##### Tabelle
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[2], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[3]` vs. `r ranges[2]` {.tabset}

##### Karte 
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[3])
```

##### Tabelle 
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[4]` vs. `r ranges[3]` {.tabset}

##### Karte 
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[4])
```

##### Tabelle 
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[2]` vs. `r ranges[1]` {.tabset}

##### Karte
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[2])
```

##### Tabelle
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[2], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[3]` vs. `r ranges[2]` {.tabset}

##### Karte 
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[3])
```

##### Tabelle 
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```

#### Title level 4 `r ranges[4]` vs. `r ranges[3]` {.tabset}

##### Karte 
```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Toner Lite")) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 47, lng = 9, popup = ranges[4])
```

##### Tabelle 
```{r}
DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
              rownames = FALSE)
```
````

**From xfun::session_info('knitr')**

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200), RStudio 1.1.453

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

Package version:
  evaluate_0.14   glue_1.2.0      graphics_3.5.1  grDevices_3.5.1 highr_0.7       knitr_1.23      magrittr_1.5   
  markdown_0.8    methods_3.5.1   mime_0.5        stats_3.5.1     stringi_1.2.3   stringr_1.3.1   tools_3.5.1    
  utils_3.5.1     xfun_0.7        yaml_2.1.19
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534247/recommended-way-to-initialize-js-renderer-in-asis-markdown-chunck/63557622?noredirect=1#comment112417672_63557622

Comment: @atusy Do you mean the part `knitr::knit_print() %>% attr('knit_meta') %>% knitr::knit_meta_add() %>% invisible()` which I could use with `leaflet() %>% ...`?

Comment: Yes, it is required to add JS dependencies. There are some alternative solutions. Maybe easy way is the one I just posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this questions was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50467457/5784831)

The trick is to use `tagList(html)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

````
---
title: "The best I got"
author: "SQC"
date: "11 Juli 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7)
library(leaflet)
ranges <- paste0("section_", c(1:3))
leaflet()
DT::datatable(data.frame())
```

# Title level 1

This is an R Markdown document. 

## Title level 2 (tab) {.tabset}

### Title level 3 (tab) {.tabset}

```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:length(ranges)) {
  cat(paste0("#### Title level 4 `r ", 
             ranges[i], "` vs. `r ", ranges[i - 1], "` {.tabset}\n"))
  cat("##### Map\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r, fig.width=8.4, fig.height=7}\n")
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    knitr::knit_print() %>%
    cat()
  cat("```\n")
  # //

  cat("##### Tabelle\n")

  # code //
  cat("```{r}\n")
  DT::datatable(data.frame(x = 1, y = ranges[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                rownames = FALSE) %>%
    knitr::knit_print() %>%
    cat()
  cat("```\n")
  # //
}
```
````

Comment: Sorry, if I run your example, only the first title is displayed correctly. The for-loop with titles and sections does not work. I tried some variants of `knitr::knit_print(), cat(), attr('knit_meta'), knitr::knit_meta_add(), invisible()` but without success. Any ideas? I can add a screenshot if you like...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this with plotly, but above codes did not work for me.

However, I look up the [R-markdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html) and found the `knit_child` function work as expected.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
res <- knitr::knit_child(text = c(
  '```{r}',
  'plotly::plot_ly(x = rnorm(100))',
  '```'
), envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE)
cat(unlist(res), sep = '\n')
```
````

Comment: I don't understand how this helps to automate nested sections. Are you able to make my example work?